# program returns odd number

Tags: c++

I am exploring c++ and I have a task to write a function that takes four integers and check which is the biggest of them  and then returns the result

The problem that I am facing is that the program returns a different number every time

I am using an online compiler (web based) to check my code output with gcc 7.2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

/*
Add `int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)` here.
*/

int max_of_four(int a, int  b, int  c, int  d){
    int num;
    // printf ("hello world ");
    int nums[] = {a,b,c,d};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

        if ( nums[i]< num ){
          //  cout << nums[i] << endl;
            ;
        }
        else if (nums[i] > num ) {
            num = nums[i];
        }
    }
    return num;
}



int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    //cout << max_of_four(a,b,c,d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What value do you expect `int num;` to start with?

Comment: Consider using [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) instead of using a manual loop.

Comment: Since you haven't initialized num, you are likely getting "stack trash" as its initial value.  So the value might be already larger than any value your user specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialized `num` with a value, so the later checks inside the loop are against a *random indeterminate* number.

```cpp
int num = a;
```

Comment: what if i am not allowed to do this ?

Comment: then start with `num[0]`

Comment: @tochka You need to set it to something, and you need to guarantee that it is not greater than any of the values you are comparing against. If you can't set `int num = a`, you could do `int num  = std::numeric_limits<int>::min;` if you `#include <limits>`

Comment: Note that reading uninitialized memory makes your program have undefined behavior. You're not guaranteed to get a random number. You could get a [nasal demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) instead. Anything is possible.

Comment: `int num = INT_MIN` would also work if you are explicitly not allowed to use an incoming value.